# Automatic photo slideshow creator (like "BlackBerry Story Maker") for Windows

Tags: windows, video, images, video-editing, slideshow

I am a big fan of [BlackBerry Story Maker](http://demos.blackberry.com/blackberry-z10/na/us/gen/how-to/media/movie-creation/blackberry-story-maker/index.html), that takes the user selected images/videos and converts them into stunning image slideshows (videos).

Unlike regular slideshow maker software, it automatically applies effects, transitions, animations, zooming, panning and what not. All the user needs is just select the images, videos, audio and that's it.

Is there any software that does the similar job on Windows 7?

I have seen a lot of software like Camtasia, AnvSoft, Magix Photostory etc., but they are not fully automatic. The user needs to manually apply all the effects and transitions. I'm in search for an automatic photo slideshow creator software (offline).

Answer (score 1):

[Wondershare Filmora](https://filmora.wondershare.com) may be the closest candidate you're looking for.

> Filmora Video Editor is an easy video editing tool for users to create
>   professional-looking videos. It comes with multiple great video
>   editing features and effects. It's very easy to learn and easy to use,
>   even people who don't have much video editing experience can start it
>   right away.

There are 2 modes in Filmora Video Editor Windows version to create videos.

After you launch Filmora Video Editor, you can see it. First, choose to create the slideshow/video in 4:3 or in 16:9. Then choose the mode you’re going to edit your media with.

[image]

**Easy Mode**: this mode helps you create a story with less editing: import media file (images, video(s)) > select a theme > choose the background music or import your own song > preview the story > export the story.

[image]

**Full Feature Mode**: all the editing features and effects are all in this mode. If you want to make a professional video or fantastic video, you’re supposed to try this mode.

Comment: There is no option for creating an **automatic** slideshow. I don't wan't to manually do the transitions. I need a software (with built in templates), that automatically transforms my images/videos into slideshows, with transitions.

Comment: Use Easy mode, it works I've been using it, it automatically adds transitions, zoom etc all you need to do is select images and click next until done